# How to add CRDs to spinnaker accounts?

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I'm looking to add support for Istio's `DestinationRule` to `Delete (Manifest)`. I believe I need to update `.deploymentConfigurations.providers.kubernetes.accounts.customResources` in  `.hal/config` to something like follows:

```yaml
- kubernetesKind: destinationrules.networking.istio.io
  versioned: false
```

It's not clear what I need to do after this. Do I need to run a command for the change to take effect? What are the steps I need to do to accomplish this change?

Notes:

- The design docs mention a command that does not exist

  - design doc: https://github.com/spinnaker/halyard/blob/master/docs/design.md#goals-and-solutions
  - command mentioned in design doc: `hal update --service clouddriver`

Answer (score 0):

For our Spinnaker Operator deployment on OpenShift, I was able to see the CRD "Kind" in the Delete (Manifest) dropdown by editing the `SpinnakerService` custom resource in our `spinnaker` namespace.  I was sure to add it to the 2nd account in the array of accounts because that's the one that needed to see the our kustom resource resources.

```
$ kubectl get spinnakerservice spinnaker -o yaml | yq .spec.spinnakerConfig.config.providers.kubernetes.accounts[1].customResources
- kubernetesKind: Kafka
  versioned: false
- kubernetesKind: KafkaUser
  versioned: false
- kubernetesKind: KafkaTopic
  versioned: false
```

After the update, all of the spinnaker pods recycled, so your setup may need a restart, too.

I still needed to manually type in my resource names, but I was at least able to finally delete my resources.